# Nebular NbEmailPassAuthProvider apparently calls API method but NbLoginComponent still shows "Something went wrong" message

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I'm trying to follow the Nebular documentation available [here](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/?utm_source=github&utm_medium=nebular_readme#/docs/auth/introduction) but still not being able to put it to work. I'm using the default `NbLoginComponent` from `@nebular/auth`, imported NbAuthModule on `app.module.ts` and a breakpoint on the API is activated when "Sign In" button hitted.

I've put a line to log the `HttpResponse` on to the browser console and it shows the info recorded in the [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPWJY.png).

But the NbLoginComponent still shows the message "Oh snap! Something went wrong." and doesn't redirect to `'/'` as configured when success.

app.module.ts:

```js
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CoreModule } from './@core/core.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ThemeModule } from './@theme/theme.module';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth-guard.service';
import {
  NbAuthModule,
  NbEmailPassAuthProvider,
} from '@nebular/auth';
import { authConfig } from './auth.config';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ThemeModule.forRoot(),
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    NbAuthModule.forRoot({
      providers: {
        email: {
          service: NbEmailPassAuthProvider,
          config: authConfig,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [NbAuthModule],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    NbEmailPassAuthProvider,
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

auth.config.ts:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { getDeepFromObject} from '@nebular/auth/helpers';
import { NgEmailPassAuthProviderConfig } from '@nebular/auth/providers/email-pass-auth.options';

export const authConfig: NgEmailPassAuthProviderConfig = {
  baseEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8080',
  login: {
    endpoint: '/auth/login',
    method: 'get',
    redirect: {
      success: '/',
      failure: null,
    },
    defaultErrors: ['Login/Email combination is not correct, please try again.'],
    defaultMessages: ['You have been successfully logged in.'],
  },
  register: {
    endpoint: '/api/auth/register',
    method: 'post',
    redirect: {
      success: '/',
      failure: null,
    },
    defaultErrors: ['Something went wrong, please try again.'],
    defaultMessages: ['You have been successfully registered.'],
  },
  logout: {
    endpoint: '/api/auth/logout',
    method: 'delete',
    redirect: {
      success: '/',
      failure: null,
    },
    defaultErrors: ['Something went wrong, please try again.'],
    defaultMessages: ['You have been successfully logged out.'],
  },
  requestPass: {
    endpoint: '/api/auth/request-pass',
    method: 'post',
    redirect: {
      success: '/',
      failure: null,
    },
    defaultErrors: ['Something went wrong, please try again.'],
    defaultMessages: ['Reset password instructions have been sent to your email.'],
  },
  resetPass: {
    endpoint: '/api/auth/reset-pass',
    method: 'put',
    redirect: {
      success: '/',
      failure: null,
    },
    resetPasswordTokenKey: 'reset_password_token',
    defaultErrors: ['Something went wrong, please try again.'],
    defaultMessages: ['Your password has been successfully changed.'],
  },
  token: {
    key: 'data.value',
    getter: (module: string, res: HttpResponse<Object>) => {
      console.log('token');
      console.log(res); // <-- the HttpResponse on the image came from this line
      getDeepFromObject(res.body,this.getConfigValue('token.key'));
    }
  },
  errors: {
    key: 'data.errors',
    getter: (module: string, res: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.log('errors');
      console.log(res);
      getDeepFromObject(res.error,
      this.getConfigValue('errors.key'),
      this.getConfigValue('${module}.defaultErrors'));
    },
  },
  messages: {
    key: 'data.messages',
    getter: (module: string, res: HttpResponse<Object>) => {
      console.log('messages');
      console.log(res);
      getDeepFromObject(res.body,
      this.getConfigValue('messages.key'),
      this.getConfigValue('${module}.defaultMessages'));
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the term  "return " in all your functions getter and  "This. GetConfigValue (' token. Key ')  "does not work here.

**you have to write :**

```
 getter: (module: string, res: HttpResponse<Object>) =>{
  console.log('token');

  console.log(res); // <-- the HttpResponse on the image came from this line
  return getDeepFromObject(res.body,'data.value',2);

          } // end getter

  }// end token
```

The backend API must send an object like this : {data:{value:x}}